# Cannot access a property or method of a null object - Won't display codeline

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, testing, typeerror

I'm having a problem with the same old TypeError #1009: Cannot acces a property or a method of a null object reference.

My problem is that when I use Ctrl + Shift + Enter. It doesn't display the codeline where the problem is. All i'm getting is :Cannot display source code at this location.

I've tried to find a solution now for several hours. but I can't. so if someone could help me with this problem I'll one happy camper.

Btw I am Using UILoaders to load pictures from an XML.

Here is my code:

```
public function bakgrund(value: XML, userData: XML):void
    {
        trace("Test bakgrund_1");
        var n:int=int(value);
        for (var i: int = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            A[i].visible=n==i;
        }
        trace("Test bakgrund_2");
    }
    public function sammaBild(value: XML, userData: XML):void 
    {
        var f: String  = value;
        pictures.image1_mc.source = f;
        pictures.image2_mc.source = f;
        pictures.image3_mc.source = f;
        pictures.image4_mc.source = f;
        trace("Test sammaBild");
    }

    public function xmlLoadedImages(event:Event):void
    {

        trace("Test xmlLoadedImages_1");
        imgData =  new XML(event.target.data);
        var imageLength:int = imgData.Vehicle.Pictures.children().length();
        for (var i: int = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
            {

                raw_image = imgData.Vehicle.Pictures.Url[i];
                imageLoader = new UILoader;
                trace("Test xmlLoadedImages_2")
                imageLoader.width = 300;
                imageLoader.height = 300;
                imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(raw_image));
                A[i].addChild(imageLoader);
            }
            trace("Test xmlLoadedImages_3")
            comment.text = imgData.Vehicle.Comment[0].children();
    }
```

Comment: I would like to add that none of the traces in this code is showing up, the only one is the one above the first function wich is in the class setup

Comment: We need more of your code, like what calls `bakgrund()` or `sammaBild()` or `xmlLoadedImages()`?

Comment: where do you define A? can one of the members in A be null?

Comment: Okay. I've changed my approach on this project, and now I don't need my class file, To answer Marton. I defined A in the beginning of my class, it contained 4 UILoaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey declare correctly

Wrong line

imgData =  new XML(event.target.data);

Comment: It is declared correctly above those functions. And as I said in a comment yesterday I've changed approach, thanks anyway though